# Cargo fails to compile rust-qml on Windows 10

Tags: rust, qml, rust-cargo

I want to make a GUI application using Rust on Windows 10 and I found [the qml crate](https://crates.io/crates/qml) which looks nice.

I added in my `Cargo.toml` file this dependency: `qml = "0.0.9"`, but when I run `cargo build`, I get this error:

```
> cargo build
   Compiling qml v0.0.9
error: failed to run custom build command for `qml v0.0.9`
process didn't exit successfully: `project\target\debug\build\qml-018515e4bf91189d\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute process: The specified file cannot be found. (os error 2)', user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\qml-0.0.9\build.rs:28:33
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I looked at the `build.rs` file and I saw this line:

```
fs::copy(Path::new(&manifest_dir).join("build_lib.sh"), Path::new(&out_dir).join("build_lib.sh")).unwrap();
```

Maybe I don't have the rights to do that on my account, so I tried to run it as admin, but cargo and rustc are installed in my user folder.

When I change the path, I get the error `error: no default toolchain configured`.

Answer (score 3):

[QML 0.0.9's build script doesn't support Windows](https://github.com/White-Oak/qml-rust/blob/v0.0.9/build.rs#L24-L28).

It appears that support for Windows was added in [80ccad26](https://github.com/White-Oak/qml-rust/commit/80ccad263b233166aa0bca2bb5d2a3dfe16d821e#diff-a7b0a2dee0126cddf994326e705a91ea), which seemingly hasn't been released yet.

You will need to use the version [from the git repository](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) instead:

```
[dependencies]
qml = { git = "https://github.com/White-Oak/qml-rust" }
```

Comment: @Ardakaniz it may be worth (politely!) asking the maintainer to release a new version in that case.

Comment: The last modification was 1 year ago, is it still maintened?

Comment: @Ardakaniz I don't actually know, but letting the owners know there is interest *might* help spur them to continue work. Or maybe other people (or you?) will step up to help maintain it if it's useful!